# How is the neutral kaon stable?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, antimatter, mesons

A neutral kaon is a mix of a particle and antiparticle, in layman's terms. In layman's terms, how is this possible without there being annihilation?

Comment: How did you imagine it is stable? Of course it is unstable. It *only* lives for $10^{-10}$s.

Comment: Neutral kaons are not composed of a particle and its antiparticle. See their quark content [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon).

Answer (score 0):

The kaons don't consist of two particles which are each other's antiparticle. The kaon comes in four varieties:

1,2) an up-quark with an anti-strange-quark ($u\bar{s}$) and vice-versa ($\bar{u}s$)
3,4) a down-quark with an anti-strange-quark ($d\bar{s}$) and vice-versa ($\bar{d}s$)

Since the down-quark and strange-quark have the same electric charge, these are the neutral kaons. You can figure out for yourself that the other two have an electric charge of $+1$ and $-1$.

All these four decay rapidly, but not because the two quarks are each other's anti-particle. For more info see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon) Wikipedia article (it's always handy to look on Wikipedia first before asking a question).

Comment: the question is about the **neutral** kaon